# How can I associate a street address with a Google Apps Calendar conference room resource?

Tags: google-calendar

Google [recommends naming calendar resources](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1033941), like conference rooms, like this `NYC-14-12-Boardroom-15-VC`. This means that when a user creates a meeting that will take place in that conference room, the `Where` field in the calendar invite is set to the name of the conference room (e.g. `NYC-14-12-Boardroom-15-VC`).

When a user opens a calendar invite and clicks the `Map` link just below the `Where` field, understandably, Google Maps can't turn the conference room name into a location. This isn't that big of a deal.

More importantly, the Google Now and Android integrations into a users calendar use the `Where` field to dynamically remind the user when they need to leave from their current location to reach the destination in a calendar item in time for the meeting. With the `Where` field containing no information as to the street address of the building that the conference room is in, this integration is not possible.

How can one create a conference room resource that has a street address associated with it? Can the conference room be named in such a way as to contain the street address (e.g. `NYC-14-12-Boardroom-15-VC 123 First St. New York, NY 10002`)?